# Google Calendar adding hour to vCal events despite setting BST and using local time format

Tags: google-calendar-api, icalendar, vcalendar

I'm generating a dynamic vCalendar file so staff can subscribe via their favourite calendaring app (mostly Apple iCal or Google Calendar). Apple iCal works fine, but no matter what I do, I can't seem to get Google Calendar to show the right time. It appears to be treating the time as UTC/GMT and automatically adding an hour even though I'm not using the 'Z' suffix on the DTSTART/DTEND dates to show it's already a local time.

I started with a simple format which didn't bother with describing daylight savings since the dates where already local:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//My Calendar//Pix//EN
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:PUBLISH
X-WR-TIMEZONE:Europe/London
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20150730T193000
DTEND:20150730T211500
DTSTAMP:20150704T113005
UID:8252@mycalendar
CLASS:PUBLIC
CREATED:20150701T100000
DESCRIPTION:Cabaret
LAST-MODIFIED:20150704T072253
SEQUENCE:0
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SUMMARY:The Supreme Fabulettes
LOCATION: White Rose Rotunda
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

This works fine in iCal, but not in Google Calendar, so I added the VTIMEZONE stuff after the X-WR-TIMEZONE declaration above:

```
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:Europe/London
X-LIC-LOCATION:Europe/London
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
DTSTART:19700330T010000
TZOFFSETFROM:+0000
TZOFFSETTO:+0100
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYDAY=-1SU;BYMONTH=3
TZNAME:BST
END:DAYLIGHT
BEGIN:STANDARD
DTSTART:19701026T020000
TZOFFSETFROM:+0100
TZOFFSETTO:+0000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYDAY=-1SU;BYMONTH=10
TZNAME:STANDARD
END:STANDARD
END:VTIMEZONE
```

This still works in iCal, but Google Calendar still insists on adding an hour to every event.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it turns out the above is working. The problem is Google Calendar caching. If you unsubscribe and re-add a URL, it still uses the cached version. Putting a dummy query on the end of the URL forced Google to refresh and hey presto, it's displaying the times properly now.